# npm gets stuck on fetching some packages, after using --verbose, nothing happens in the CLI

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm using VSCod and cmd to fetch some npm packages, but it gets stuck after a couple of dozen packages, almost always on one package that's a dependency (like, this one time, vue-uploader). I don't know what's the issue. I've never had this problem. My internet speed is about 5mbps. What's could be wrong?

Comment: Try to install it on a fresh project and see if it gets stuck again. Try to remove it from `package.json` and install it separately. Also, could you please post a screenshot of the console?

Comment: Could you please try these commands.. "npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/" "npm set progress=false"

Comment: If above doesn't work try removing "package-lock.json". https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17228

Comment: @PALLAMOLLASAI I think that it's just one package that's doing this. vue-uploader@post-install. Why?

Comment: can you please show what command you entered and what was the cmd output??